# Writing a lua_Reader function in C

Tags: c, lua

As part of the Lua library in C, there is the function `lua_load` for loading Lua chunks. The second parameter to this function is a `lua_Reader`, which is "a user-supplied `reader` function to read the chunk." A `lua_Reader` is defined as this:

`typedef const char* (*lua_Reader)(lua_State* L, void* data, size_t* size);`

My question is how to write such a function that can be supplied to `lua_load`. I have not been able to find any useful examples online.

Some links that provide information but have not been enough to help me write such a function:

http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_load

http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_Reader

More specifically, I do not understand the data parameter for the function `lua_load`. It is listed as a `void*`, though I would assume one would pass a `const char*` or `char*` to it. However, I do not understand where it comes from. Is it pulled off the Lua stack?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `data` could be used as a "context".  For example, you can create two instances of a reader using single function `lua_Reader`.  These two readers will differ by `data` argument, which will allow them to implement different functionality depending on `data`.  The "context" is an C-ish way to implement OOP-like objects and methods (function is a method, `data` is an object this method is applied to).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation on [`lua_Reader`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_Reader) itself, instead of `lua_load`. It explains the requirements of the function in detail:

> The reader function used by `lua_load`. Every time it needs another piece of the chunk, `lua_load` calls the reader, passing along its data parameter. The reader must return a pointer to a block of memory with a new piece of the chunk and set size to the block size. The block must exist until the reader function is called again. To signal the end of the chunk, the reader must return `NULL` or set size to zero. The reader function may return pieces of any size greater than zero.